# Как сделать иллюзию того, что линия проходит в букву насквозь через отверстие, а не поверх нее

Tags: css, html5, svg, canvas, svg-animation

[image: пример того как выглядит, а заголовок то что должно получиться]

пример того как выглядит, а заголовок то что должно получиться

Answer (score 11):

Сложный способ:

Можно что-то подобное изобразить на канве, это конечно не буфер глубины, но подход в целом тот же. Тут еще необходимо поработать со смешиванием, для удаления черных пикселей

1. рисуем текст на одной канве а линию на другой
2. объединяем изображения, имитируя буфер глубины

```js
let ctx1 = canvas1.getContext('2d'), 
    ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d"), 
    w = canvas1.width, h = canvas1.height;
    
requestAnimationFrame(draw)

function draw(t) {
    requestAnimationFrame(draw)
    drawText(ctx1);
    drawLine(ctx2, t);
    composeImages();
}

function composeImages(){
    let imageData1 = ctx1.getImageData(0, 0, w, h);
    let imageData2 = ctx2.getImageData(0, 0, w, h);
    for (let x=0; x<w; x++) {
        for (let y=0; y<h; y++) {
            let o = (y*w+x)*4;

            // если прозрачность пикселя картинки, где нарисована 
            // линия меньше 100 - оставляем текст
            if (imageData2.data[o+3]<100) continue;

            // если пиксель левее центра буквы и данные пикселя есть 
            // (не 0 прозрачность) в обоих канвах, берем в качестве источника
            // канву, где нарисована линия, иначе - берем канву с текстом
            let src = x < 145 || !imageData1.data[o+3] ? imageData2 : imageData1;
            for (let i=0;i<4;i++)
              imageData1.data[o+i] = src.data[o+i];
        }
    }
    ctx1.putImageData(imageData1, 0, 0);    
}

function drawText(ctx) {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
    ctx.fillStyle="white";
    ctx.font="50px Arial"
    ctx.fillText("example text",10,90)
}

function drawLine(ctx, t){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
    ctx.strokeStyle= `hsl(${Math.sin(t/1400)*180},75%,75%)`
    ctx.lineWidth = 4+Math.sin(t/500)
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.moveTo(90+Math.sin(t/300)*5,10)
    ctx.lineTo(200,140+Math.cos(t/500)*5)
    ctx.stroke()    
}
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas1 style='background:black' />
<canvas id=canvas2 style='display:none'/>
```

Answer (score 10):

В предыдущих ответах уже были высказаны идеи, как реализовать эффект прохождения линии сквозь текст:

**1. @hu-fo-of-ex**

> В голову приходит только вариант с двумя линиями, но как ты это будешь
>   анимировать, я не знаю.

---

**2. @Анатолий Шевелев**

> Можно часть линии, которая проходит "под" буквой, перекрыть
>   каким-нибудь белым блоком.

Конечно эти идеи лежат на поверхности, но как их реализовать?

*Техника реализации по шагам*

Это универсальный подход для реализации верстки точь в точь по макету дизайнера. При этом не надо высчитывать, подбирать отступы, пропорции взаимного расположения элементов вёрстки, мучатся с адаптивным дизайном. Всё будет адаптивно, на месте, не развалится при смене размера дисплея.

- Загружаем в векторный редактор SVG файл со скриншотом автора вопроса

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="302" height="218" viewBox="0 0 302 218" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"  >  

<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCPht.png" width="100%" height="100%" /> 

</svg>
```

- Используя существующие контуры линии рисуем инструментом - `"Рисовать
  кривые Безье и прямые линии"`(красная стрелка на рисунке)  вдоль
  направляющей три линии (зелёные стрелки)

Линия номер 2 будет закрашена белым цветом под фон буквы, линии 1 и 3 будут закрашены фиолетовым цветом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Каждая буква имеет свой `path` Для этого в векторном редакторе после
  написания текста выбираем в меню  - **Контур \ Оконтурить объект**
- Сохраняем файл в формате *.svg
- Прогоняем его через оптимизатор [SVG-EDITOR](https://petercollingridge.appspot.com/svg-editor)
- Для создания объема добавляем тень буквам и линиям

```
<defs>
    <filter id="dropshadow" height="130%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3"/> 
      <feOffset dx="4" dy="10" result="offsetblur"/> 
      <feMerge> 
        <feMergeNode/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/> 
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>
```

- Добавляем анимацию покачивания линии - поворот на 10 градусов и обратно

```
<animateTransform xlink:href="#gr1"
  attributeName="transform"
type="rotate"
values="
0 119 112.5;
10 119 112.5;
0 119 112.5"
dur="4s"
repeatCount="indefinite"/>
```

Полный код

```css
.container {
width:50%;
height:50%;
}
.s0{
 -inkscape-font-specification:Tahoma;
 fill:#fff;
 font-family:Tahoma;
 font-size:53.3;
 letter-spacing:0;
 line-height:13;
 word-spacing:0;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 302 218" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">


   <defs>
    <filter id="dropshadow" height="130%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3"/> 
      <feOffset dx="4" dy="10" result="offsetblur"/> 
      <feMerge> 
        <feMergeNode/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/> 
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>
   <!-- Фон -->
 <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#1E2248" />
 
 <!-- Каждая буква имеет свой path -->
  <g transform="translate(2)" filter="url(#dropshadow)">
    <g aria-label="CRUITED" class="s0" >
      <path d="m20.5 96.3q-3.8 0-7-1.3Q10.3 93.8 8 91.2 5.7 88.7 4.4 84.9 3.1 81.2 3.1 76.3q0-4.9 1.2-8.5 1.3-3.6 3.6-6.3 2.3-2.6 5.5-4 3.2-1.4 7.1-1.4 2 0 3.6 0.3 1.7 0.3 3.2 0.7 1.3 0.4 2.6 1 1.3 0.6 2.6 1.3v6.2h-0.4q-0.7-0.6-1.7-1.5-1.1-0.9-2.6-1.7-1.5-0.8-3.2-1.3-1.7-0.5-4-0.5-2.5 0-4.7 1-2.2 1-3.9 3-1.6 2-2.6 5-0.9 3-0.9 6.7 0 4 1 6.9 1 2.9 2.6 4.8 1.6 1.9 3.8 2.9 2.2 1 4.6 1 2.2 0 4.1-0.5 1.9-0.5 3.4-1.4 1.4-0.8 2.5-1.6 1-0.9 1.6-1.5h0.4v6.1q-1.3 0.6-2.4 1.1-1.1 0.5-2.7 1.1-1.7 0.5-3.2 0.8-1.4 0.3-3.7 0.3z"/>
      <path d="M67.4 95.6H60.7L48.4 80.2h-5.9v15.4h-5.2V56.8h10q3.3 0 5.6 0.4 2.3 0.4 4.3 1.7 2 1.3 3.2 3.4 1.2 2.1 1.2 5.1 0 4.3-2.2 7.1-2.2 2.9-5.9 4.2zM56.3 67.7q0-1.7-0.6-3-0.6-1.3-1.8-2.2-1.1-0.7-2.6-1-1.5-0.3-3.6-0.3h-5.1v14.6h4.5q2.2 0 4-0.4 1.8-0.4 3-1.6 1.1-1.1 1.6-2.6 0.5-1.5 0.5-3.5z"/>
      <path d="m84.1 96.4q-3.4 0-6-0.9-2.6-0.9-4.3-2.7-2-2-2.9-4.8-0.8-2.8-0.8-7V56.8h5.2v24.2q0 2.7 0.3 4.5 0.3 1.8 1.3 3.3 1 1.6 2.8 2.4 1.8 0.8 4.4 0.8 2.4 0 4.3-0.8 1.9-0.8 2.9-2.4 1-1.5 1.3-3.3 0.4-1.8 0.4-4.4V56.8h5.2v24.2q0 4-0.8 6.9-0.8 2.9-2.9 4.9-1.8 1.8-4.3 2.7-2.4 0.9-6 0.9z"/>
      <path d="M119.1 95.6H104v-4h4.9V60.8h-4.9v-4h15.1v4h-4.9v30.9h4.9z"/>
      <path d="M134.5 95.6V61.4h-13v-4.6h31.2v4.6H139.6v34.2z"/>
      <path d="M156.6 95.6V56.8h24.2v4.6h-19.1v10.6h17.8v4.6h-17.8v14.4h19.1v4.6z"/>
      <path d="m217 76.3q0 5.3-2.2 9.6-2.1 4.3-5.8 6.7-2.9 1.8-6 2.5-3 0.6-7.7 0.6h-8.9V56.8h8.8q5.5 0 8.6 0.8 3.1 0.8 5.3 2.2 3.8 2.5 5.8 6.6 2.1 4.1 2.1 9.8zm-5.4-0.1q0-4.5-1.5-7.6-1.5-3.2-4.4-4.9-2.1-1.2-4.4-1.8-2.3-0.5-5.8-0.5h-3.9v29.9h3.9q3.4 0 6-0.5 2.6-0.5 4.7-2 2.7-1.8 4-4.8 1.4-3 1.4-7.6z"/>
    </g>
    <g aria-label="PLAY CO" class="s0">
      <path d="m125.9 114.7q0 2.5-0.9 4.8-0.9 2.2-2.5 3.8-2 2-4.7 3-2.7 1-6.8 1h-4.4v14.5h-5.2v-38.8h9.7q3.4 0 5.9 0.6 2.4 0.6 4.3 1.8 2.2 1.5 3.4 3.8 1.2 2.3 1.2 5.5zm-5.4 0.1q0-2-0.7-3.5-0.7-1.5-2.1-2.4-1.2-0.8-2.9-1.1-1.6-0.3-4-0.3h-4.3v15.5h3.5q3.1 0 5.1-0.5 1.9-0.5 3.2-1.8 1.1-1.2 1.7-2.6 0.5-1.4 0.5-3.2zM153.2 141.8"/>
      <path d="m153.2 141.8h-22.5v-38.8h5.2v34.2h17.3z"/>
      <path d="m153.1 141.8 13.1-38.8h6.4l13.1 38.8h-5.4l-3.5-10.8h-14.8l-3.5 10.8zm22.1-15.2-6-18.3-6 18.3z"/>
      <path d="m216.4 103-13.1 21.6v17.2h-5.2V125.2L185.1 103h5.7l10 17.1 10.2-17.1z"/>
      <path d="m251.9 142.5q-3.8 0-7-1.3-3.2-1.3-5.5-3.8-2.3-2.5-3.6-6.3-1.3-3.8-1.3-8.7 0-4.9 1.2-8.5 1.3-3.6 3.6-6.3 2.3-2.6 5.5-4 3.2-1.4 7.1-1.4 2 0 3.6 0.3 1.7 0.3 3.2 0.7 1.3 0.4 2.6 1 1.3 0.6 2.6 1.3v6.2h-0.4q-0.7-0.6-1.7-1.5-1.1-0.9-2.6-1.7-1.5-0.8-3.2-1.3-1.7-0.5-4-0.5-2.5 0-4.7 1-2.2 1-3.9 3-1.6 2-2.6 5-0.9 3-0.9 6.7 0 4 1 6.9 1 2.9 2.6 4.8 1.6 1.9 3.8 2.9 2.2 1 4.6 1 2.2 0 4.1-0.5 1.9-0.5 3.4-1.4 1.4-0.8 2.5-1.6 1-0.9 1.6-1.5h0.4v6.1q-1.3 0.6-2.4 1.1-1.1 0.5-2.7 1.1-1.7 0.5-3.2 0.8-1.4 0.3-3.7 0.3z"/>
      <path d="m296.2 107.5q2.2 2.6 3.4 6.3 1.2 3.8 1.2 8.6 0 4.7-1.2 8.5-1.2 3.8-3.5 6.4-2.4 2.7-5.5 4-3.2 1.3-7 1.3-3.9 0-7.1-1.3-3.2-1.3-5.4-4-2.2-2.6-3.4-6.4-1.2-3.8-1.2-8.5 0-4.9 1.2-8.6 1.2-3.7 3.5-6.4 2.2-2.6 5.4-3.9 3.2-1.4 7.1-1.4 4 0 7.1 1.4 3.2 1.4 5.4 3.9zm-0.7 14.9q0-3.9-0.8-6.8-0.8-3-2.3-4.9-1.5-2-3.7-3-2.2-1-4.9-1-2.8 0-4.9 1-2.1 1-3.7 3-1.5 2-2.4 5-0.8 3-0.8 6.8 0 7.6 3.2 11.7 3.2 4 8.6 4 5.4 0 8.6-4 3.2-4.1 3.2-11.7z"/>
    </g>
  </g>
   <!-- Линии 1,2,3 -->
  <g id="gr1" stroke-width="4" filter="url(#dropshadow)"  >
  <path d="M61.9 179.9 117 109" stroke="#5E3DB3" />
  <path d="m118.2 107.5 2.2-2.9" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="3" />
  <path d="M121.1 103.8 180.8 27" stroke="#5E3DB3" />
  
  </g> 
    <!-- Анимация поворота линии на угол 0 - 10deg - 0 -->
   <animateTransform xlink:href="#gr1"
      attributeName="transform"
      type="rotate"
      values="
       0 119 112.5;
       10 119 112.5;
       0 119 112.5"
       dur="4s"
       repeatCount="indefinite"/>
</svg>
</div>
```

**Приложение полностью адаптивно, работает во всех современных браузерах, кроме IE**

Answer (score 6):

В голову приходит только вариант с двумя линиями, но как ты это будешь анимировать, я не знаю.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 5rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 160px;
  width: 10px;
  
  background-color: tomato;
}

.hello__line {
  transform: translateX(160px) rotate(50deg);
  z-index: -1;
}

.worlds__line {
  transform: translateX(50px) rotate(50deg);
}
```

```html
<div class='hello'>hello <span class="hello__line line"></span></div>
<div class='worlds'>world <span class="worlds__line line"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

А зачем вам это? Экспортируйте картинку с линией как одно целое из дизайна) Ведь в дизайне, наверно, линия проходит так как вам нужно?)

Comment: Либо мудрить со стилями... Но на много ж проще картинку взять)

Comment: я бы с удовольствием взял бы картинку и все) Да вот только мне потом анимацию с линией делать надо...

Comment: Попробуйте координатами найти эту часть линии и задать opacity: 0;... только заморочки)

Comment: @ZUGR а какой характер анимации? предлагаю сразу это все нарисовать на канве или svg

Answer (score 2):

Можно часть линии, которая проходит "под" буквой, перекрыть каким-нибудь белым блоком.
Конечно придется этому блоку задать абсолютное позиционирование `position: absolute` и `z-index` больше чем у надписи и у линии. 
Могут возникнуть проблемы если сама надпись тоже должна анимироваться